# Linux not resuming from s2ram (X570, Zen3)

Tags: gentoo, suspend, acpi, amd

I have a fresh install of Gentoo Linux on a MSI X570 Tomahawk, AMD 5900X machine with the latest BIOS (`7C84v163`).

`5.10.27-gentoo-x86_64` kernel fails to resume from Suspend-to-RAM. First, `s2ram` complains about an unknown machine:

```
Machine is unknown.
This machine can be identified by:
    sys_vendor   = ""
    sys_product  = ""
    sys_version  = ""
    bios_version = ""
```

I tried different combinations of `s2ram` parameters with `-f`, but nothing really works.

I followed the [official guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/s2ram.html) to debug it, got the following output:

```
[    0.950772] PM:   Magic number: 0:356:126
[    0.951563] input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2f:00.4/sound/card1/input9
[    0.951909] PM:   hash matches drivers/base/power/main.c:904
[    0.953107] input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2f:00.4/sound/card1/input10
[    0.954349] acpi device:01: hash matches
```

no other matches. Trying to find the device:

```
amd /usr/src/linux # ls -l /sys/bus/acpi/devices/device\:01/physical_node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 16 21:42 /sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:01/physical_node -> ../../../../pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1
amd /usr/src/linux # lspci | grep "00:01.1"
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
```

I'd like to try `S1/standby` as a workaround, but it is not supported for some reason:

```
amd ~ # cat /sys/power/state 
freeze mem disk
amd ~ # cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
s2idle [deep]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find what's wrong with `s2ram` but a simple `echo mem > /sys/power/state` works

Comment: If you use loginctl, then `loginctl suspend` should be the proper way to suspend your system. With systemd `systemctl suspend`.